# What does the Honorable Chairman mean?

Tags: parliament, india, terminology

I simply want to know what does the **Honorable Chairman** Nominated mean?
[Javed Akthar](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Javed_Akhtar) is a nominated Rajya Sabha member hence nominated, but what is that Honorable Chairman, how is that title earned.

Here is the link to the entire [Rajya Sabha video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5Z0dLDSvth8)

[image]

Comment: "The Honorable" is just a title given to various positions

Comment: In particular "Honorable" is used to British MPs and other countries using both the English language and the Westminster system. India probably carries it over.

Comment: Typically it's a ritual, a convention only without any further meaning. People in distinguished positions sometimes are given "honorary" additional tags to their names when addressing them, with the simplest of them probably "honorable". It doesn't imply a copious amount of honor though, it's just a custom. For example, the boss of my local university is sometimes called "magnificence" even though for all practical purposes he is just a human like the rest of us.

Comment: @DJClayworth - *"British MPs are Honourable"* - [Citation required]

Comment: @Valorum British MPs are Honourable, by definition; they may or may not be honourable…

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You misunderstand - the title of "Honourable Chairman" does not refer to Javed Akhtar. As you noticed he is just a *nominated* Member of Parliament:

> Twelve members are nominated to the *Rajya Sabha* by the President of India for six-years term for their contributions towards arts, literature, sciences, and social services. This right has been bestowed upon the President according to the Fourth Schedule (Articles 4(1) and 80(2)) of the Constitution of India. - [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_nominated_members_of_the_Rajya_Sabha)

In the *Rajya Sabha*, the vice-President of India also officiates as its de-facto *[Chairman](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vice_President_of_India)*. A deputy Chairman is also elected by the Rajya Sabha. When the vice-President is absent, the [deputy Chairperson](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deputy_Chairperson_of_the_Rajya_Sabha) runs the house.

The caption in the video by *Rajya Sabha TV* is conveying two information:

1. "*In the chair: Hon'ble Chairman*" means that this session of the *Rajya Sabha* is being run by the Chairman (vice-President) himself.
2. "*Javed Akhtar, Nominated*" is informing the viewer that the person who is currently speaking is Javed Akhtar and that he is a nominated Member of Parliament.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification, that explains everything